# Mongodb aggregate not returning correct date

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to return results from MongoDB (using PHP) where I have the following output:
username, # of expeditions, # of transcriptions, last transcription date

The query I use is

```
$collection->aggregate([
[
    '$match' => [
        'subject_projectId' => (int) $projectId
    ]
],
[
    '$sort' => [
        'classification_finished_at' => -1
    ]
],
[
    '$group' => [
        '_id' => '$user_name',
        'transcriptionCount' => [
            '$sum' => 1
        ],
        'expedition' => [
            '$addToSet' => '$subject_expeditionId'
        ],
        'last_date' => [
            '$first' => '$classification_finished_at'
        ]
    ]
],
[
    '$project' => [
        '_id' => 0,
        'user_name' => '$_id',
        'transcriptionCount' => 1,
        'expeditionCount' => [
            '$size' => '$expedition'
        ],
        'last_date' => 1
    ]
]]);
```

I'm getting the correct return for everything but the last date. Instead of giving me the last date a user did a transcription, it gives me some other date. Not sure what date is being given, I just know there are later dates for some users.
Would like to know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**`$min`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/) or [**`$max`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) with the `last_date`

```
[
    '$group' => [
        '_id' => '$user_name',
        'transcriptionCount' => [
            '$sum' => 1
        ],
        'expedition' => [
            '$addToSet' => '$subject_expeditionId'
        ],
        'last_date' => [
            '$min' => '$classification_finished_at'
        ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly.